# .Refresh BackgroundQuery:= False causing VBA error 1004 - Expression.Error - Source not recognized

Tags: excel, vba

Struggling with an issue in VBA.  The query below runs when I'm running a standard import and utilizing record macro.  However, once I added variables to the equation, I'm now getting this error when I get to the .Refresh statement.  I've spent a considerable amount of time researching this but I've not found a solution.  I've read that this could be a "false" error but not sure.
If anyone has some insight, I would appreciate it.  If you need any more info, please let me know.

```
Dim x As String
Dim FileToOpen As String

FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename   '-- Name of file to import
```

'-- Generate name for query and new sheet

```
x = "SAP_Data_asof_" & Mid(FileToOpen, InStrRev(FileToOpen, " ") + 1, 256)
x = Left(x, InStr(x, ".") - 1)
If x = ActiveWorkbook.Queries(x) Then
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries(x).Delete
End If

ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:=x, Formula:= _
    "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents(""" & FileToOpen & """, null, true)," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Sheet1_Sheet = Source{[Item=""Sheet1"",Kind=""Sheet""]}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Promoted Headers"" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Sheet1_Sheet, [PromoteAllScalars=true])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#" & _
    """Promoted Headers"",{{""Org Unit"", Int64.Type}, {""Org Unit Abbr"", type text}, {""Org Unit Text"", type text}, {""Validity Date"", type date}, {""Position"", Int64.Type}, {""Position Abbr"", type text}, {""Position Text"", type text}, {""CC OR"", type text}, {""Job Level"", type text}, {""Cost Center"", Int64.Type}, {""WFC Identifier"", type text}, {""Cost Center" & _
    " Text"", type text}, {""PersNo"", Int64.Type}, {""Employee_App First N"", type text}, {""Middle Name"", type text}, {""Last Name"", type text}, {""Known As"", type text}, {""Job Key"", Int64.Type}, {""Job Abbr"", type text}, {""Job Text"", type text}, {""Job Cat"", Int64.Type}, {""Job Cat Text"", type text}, {""Co Code"", Int64.Type}, {""Co Code Text"", type text}, " & _
    "{""Bus Area"", Int64.Type}, {""Business Area Text"", type text}, {""PA"", Int64.Type}, {""PA Text"", type text}, {""PSA"", type text}, {""PSA Text"", type text}, {""EG"", Int64.Type}, {""EG Text"", type text}, {""ESG"", Int64.Type}, {""ESG Text"", type text}, {""Chief Position"", Int64.Type}, {""Chief Title"", type text}, {""Chief Name"", type text}, {""Rpts To (A-0" & _
    "02)"", type text}, {""Reports to Title"", type text}, {""Reports to PERNR"", type text}, {""Reports to Name"", type text}, {""Takes Dir(A-DIR)"", Int64.Type}, {""Takes Direction from Title"", type text}, {""Takes Direction from PERNR"", type text}, {""Takes Direction from Name"", type text}, {""WC State"", type text}, {""WC State Text"", type text}, {""WC Code"", In" & _
    "t64.Type}, {""WC Code Text"", type text}, {""Obsolete"", type text}, {""Vacant"", type date}, {""First Name (Romaji)"", type text}, {""Last Name (Romaji)"", type text}, {""OU Func"", Int64.Type}, {""OU Function Text"", type text}})," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Removed Other Columns"" = Table.SelectColumns(#""Changed Type"",{""Position"", ""Position Text"", ""Job Level"", ""Cost Center" & _
    """, ""WFC Identifier"", ""Cost Center Text"", ""Last Name"", ""Known As"", ""Chief Name""})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Removed Other Columns"""


ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheets("Labor_Detail")).Name = x
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
    "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location= " & x & " ;Extended Properties=""""" _
    , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
    .CommandType = xlCmdSql
    .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [" & x & "]")
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
    .ListObject.DisplayName = x
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and after some attempts, I discovered that if you use the code of a recorded macro, this code must not be inside a loop of any type.

It seems that this is not the case. However, your problem might be similar, and maybe the problem is in the queries deleting part. Try this instead:

Dim pq As Object
For Each pq In ThisWorkbook.Queries
pq.Delete
Next

If this does not work, please give me the parts of the recorded macro that you've changed.

Best regards,

Mike